# Rails 3 stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag do not work after update

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` have stopped working after I updated rails from 2.x to 3.1.3 (3.1.0)

Log

```
Started GET "/urls/604" for 77.88.42.27 at Mon Nov 21 11:00:20 +0200 2011
  Processing by UrlsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"604", "collection"=>{"tag_suggestions"=>:get}}
  Url Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `urls`.* FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "604"]]
  Comment Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE (is_active = 1 AND url_id = '604') ORDER      BY created_at DESC
Rendered shared/_comments.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered urls/show.html.erb within layouts/application (57.6ms)
Compiled global.css  (0ms)  (pid 28092)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 663ms

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
    19:   -->
    20: 
    21: 
    22:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'global' %>
    23:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.4.min.js' %>
    24:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.corner.js' %>
    25:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1824233644_17244817840'
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your CSS file valid? It may be that something in there (possibly an old browser hack or similar non-standard syntax) is tripping up Sprockets.

You might find this useful for learning about how Rails 3 manages CSS/JS http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: My css valid, i check it. In addition

Comment: In additional i try to clear my css file and use it as blank css file. In logs i saw the same error: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)) for line <%= stylesheet_link_tag "global" %>

Comment: @prosto.vint Why is this the accepted answer if it did not provide a solution that solved your problem?

Comment: @TylerH I don`t remember :(

Answer (score 0):

We saw this error after moving form Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1.  Our problem was that we had a helper in application_helper.rb called asset_path.  asset_path is critical to Rails 3.1 and we were inadvertently overriding it.